# WPF ListView Measure and Arrange issue with bound ItemsSource vs manually added items

Tags: wpf, listview, binding

I have a series of UserControls intended for printing purposes only. They are mainly tables implemented with ListView & GridView. Each control has a backing view model, and the ItemSource of the ListView is bound to the view model. All pretty standard. When I actually print these controls to PDF, they display the bound data without an issue. The trouble arises when I am trying to Measure and Arrange the individual controls so that I can determine how many rows will fit on that page.

```xml
<UserControl>
   <Grid>
      <ListView x:Name="ItemsListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
         <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
               <GridView.Columns>
                  <GridViewColumn Header="Column Name 1" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Column_Property_1}" />
                  <GridViewColumn Header="Column Name 2" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Column_Property_2}" />
               </GridView.Columns>     
            </GridView>
         </ListView.View>
      </ListView>
   </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

```cs
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    private readonly ViewModel _viewModel;

    public MyControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public MyControl(ViewModel viewModel) :this()
    {
        _viewModel = viewModel;
        this.DataContext = _viewModel;
    }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<MyItem> Items { get; set; }
}

public class MyItem
{
    public string Column_Property_1 { get; set; }
    public string Column_Property_2 { get; set; }
}
```

When I Measure and Arrange the control in the pagination service, the ActualHeight of the control is always `{ 0, 0 }`.

```cs
public Size GetMeasuredSize(UserControl control)
{
    control.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
    control.Arrage(new Rect(control.DesiredSize));
    control.UpdateLayout();

    return new Size(control.ActualWidth, control.ActualHeight);
}
```

What I have found though, by inspecting the control in the debugger during the GetMeasureSize method, is that the Items property on the ListView control is not populated at all by the binding- the count is 0. So it makes sense that its desired size and actual sizes are 0, it just doesn't have any items to dispay.

If I remove the binding and manually add each item from my view model, it's a completely different story, and I get the correct ActualWidth and ActualHeight from the control.

```cs
public MyControl(ViewModel viewModel) :this()
{
    _viewModel = viewModel;
    this.DataContext = _viewModel;

    foreach (var item in _viewModel.Items)
    {
        ItemsListView.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Obviously, that is a little less than desirable. So I'm hoping that someone can either help explain this behavior and point me in the right direction to get this working with the bindings.

I've tried "force updating" the binding in the MeasureOverride method

`ItemsListView.GetBindingExpression(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty).UpdateTarget();`
`BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(ItemsListView, ListView.ItemsSourceProperty).UpdateTarget();`

Neither resulted in the items property being populated.

Update:
I've just found this:
[Customized Measure / Arrange algorithms on controls that use Data Binding in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574009/customized-measure-arrange-algorithms-on-controls-that-use-data-binding-in-wpf?rq=1)

which sheds some light on the situation.

Comment: When the control is intended for printing only, and you need its final size immediately after construction with a view model parameter, why are you using data binding at all (which is always evaluated after construction of the control)? Why is the second approach less desirable, when it simply does what you need? You would not need a ViewModel field and explicitly set the control's DataContext, but just `ItemsListView.ItemsSource = viewModel.Items;`

Comment: @Clemens Because the view model is not as simple as this striped-out example.